# Proving orthogonal matrices are a subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-writing

> Recall that the transpose of an $m \times n$ matrix $B = [b_{ij}]$, denoted by $B^\top$,  is the $n \times m$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-entry is $a_{ji}$. Show that 
>   $$ O_n (\mathbb{R}):= \left\{ Q \in GL_n (\mathbb{R}) : Q^\top Q = Q Q^\top = I_n \right\} \leq GL_n (\mathbb{R}), $$
>   where $I_n$ denotes the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

My I have 3 questions here.  The first being, is I don't really understand  what I am trying to prove. I think I need to prove that $O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of all n by n matrixes. And $O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a set of all n by n matrices whose transpose times themselves is the identity matrix. **Is my understanding correct?** my second question is **could I use either the one step subgroup test or the two step subgroup test ?** My final question is if I cannot use the subgroup tests to prove this what should I do instead?

My title was horrid, but I could not think of a better one, you any of you can please change my title. Thanks

Comment: I'm not famiilar with the "one step" and "two step" subgroup tests.  What are they?

Comment: One step: if there is a group A and B is $\subseteq$ to A, A is not an empty set. And $a*b^{-1} \in B$ whenever a,b$\in$A, then $B \leqslant A.    Basically you prove its not empty then prove $a*b^{-1} \in B$

Comment: Two step: let A $\subseteq B$, and A is not and empty set, then a*b $\in$ A whenever a,b $\in$ A and $a^{-1} \in A $ whenever a $\in$H . Then $A\leqslant B$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are supposed to show $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup.  Not a subgroup “of all $n\times n$ matrices,” since that's not actually a group.  Rather, you are asked to show $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, the group of all *invertible* $n\times n$ matrices.

I looked up the one-step and two-step subgroup tests.  Either of them will work.  For the one-step test, you need to show that for all $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ in $O_n(\mathbb{R})$, $Q_1Q_2^{-1} \in O_n(\mathbb{R})$.  For the two-step process, you would need to know that $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is closed under matrix multiplication and matrix inversion.

For either test, the following facts are essential:  If $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices, then
\begin{align*}
    (AB)^{-1} &= B^{-1} A^{-1} \\
    (AB)^T    &= B^T A^T \\
    (A^{-1})^T &= (A^T)^{-1} \\
\end{align*}

I hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: I thought $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R}) $ was the group of all n by n matrices if it is not, what does it stand for?

Comment: @blueberry No - $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices. It is called the general linear group.

Comment: So for step one the proof is:

Let $A,B\in O_n{F}$ we need to show that $AB^{-1}\in O_n{F}$

$(AB^{-1})^t=(B^{-1})^tA^t=(B^t)^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB^t)^{-1}=(AB^{-1})^t$ and therefore $AB^{-1}\in  O_n{F}$ and $O_n{F}\leq GL_n(F)$