# Is $O_{n}(F)$ Subgroup Of GL_{n}(F)

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Are The Orthogonal Matrices $O_{n}(F)=\{A\in GL_{n}(F):A^{T}=A^{-1}\}\subseteq GL_n{F}?$

1. $I_{n}\in O_{n}(F)$ and therefore $O_{n}(F)\neq \emptyset$
2. a. $\forall A,B\in O_{n}(F)$  $(AB)^{T}=B^TA^T=B^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}$

   b.Another approach $\forall A,B\in O_{n}(F)$ $Det(AB)=Det(A)Det(B)=\pm 1 \cdot \pm 1= \pm 1 \in O_{n}(F)$
3. $\forall A\in O_{n}(F)$ $A^{T}=A^{-1}$ So the inverse of $A\in O_{n}(F)$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: For 3, you need to show $(A^{-1})^T=(A^{-1})^{-1}(=A)$

Comment: @A.Goodier edited, is it ok now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving orthogonal matrices are a subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488468/proving-orthogonal-matrices-are-a-subgroup)

Comment: For 3, you still need to show $O_n(F)$ is closed under inversion. For any $A\in O_n(F)$, you want to show $A^{-1}\in O_n(F)$, i.e. that $(A^{-1})^T=A$. You can do this by taking the transpose of both sides of the equation $A^T=A^{-1}$.