# Proving that $H=\{A\in GL(2,R)\mid AA^T=I\}$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I need to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,R)$ where $H=\{A\in GL(2,R)\mid AA^T=I\}$. I think I can show that $H$ is non-empty because $I$ is the identity of all $n\times n$ matrices in $GL(2,R)$ but, how do I show that it is closed? I have that $AA^T=I$ and $BB^T=I$ but can I show that $AB=I$. Is that even how I do it?

Comment: Why would you want to show that $AB=I$?

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying to show that the group is closed under the group operation and I'm confused on how to do this.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829976/o-2-mathbbr-is-a-subgroup-of-gl-2-mathbbr), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488468/proving-orthogonal-matrices-are-a-subgroup).

Answer (score 4):

Note that you have $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ (check that yourself if you are unsure).

Then if $A,B\in H$ we get

$$\begin{align}
(AB)(AB)^T &= A\underbrace{B B^T}_{=I} A^T \\
&= AA^T\\
& = I.
\end{align}$$

So $$AB\in H$$

Therefore, $H$ is closed under matrix multiplication.

Comment: I don't think this suffices, as $H$ is not finite.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $H \neq \emptyset$ since $I \in H$.

Now, suppose $A, B \in H$ and consider $AB^{-1}$. We have

$$(AB^{-1}) (AB^{-1})^\top = A (B^{-1} (B^{-1})^\top )A^\top = A I A^\top = AA^\top = I.$$

This shows that $AB^{-1} \in H$. Hence, $H$ is a subgroup by the one-step subgroup test.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.